# Can't install rfPermute package

Tags: r

I'm trying to install rfPermute in R studio and am getting errors that R studio can't install some dependency packages.  Specifically the packages: 'runjags', and 'swfscMisc'.  I think it has something to do with checking for package configuration.  Below is the feedback in the console when trying to install this package.

```
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
configure: WARNING: pkg-config file for jags 2 unavailable
configure: WARNING: Consider adding the directory containing `jags.pc`
configure: WARNING: to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
```

Any idea why this isn't working?

Below is the result when trying to install 'runjags', and ‘swfscMisc’.

```
* installing *source* package ‘runjags’ ...
** package ‘runjags’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
configure: WARNING: pkg-config file for jags 2 unavailable
configure: WARNING: Consider adding the directory containing `jags.pc`
configure: WARNING: to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
configure: Attempting legacy configuration of rjags
checking for jags... no
configure: error: "automatic detection of JAGS failed. Please use pkg-config to locate the JAGS library. See the INSTALL file for details."
ERROR: configuration failed for package ‘runjags’
* removing ‘/home/carlson51/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/runjags’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘runjags’ had non-zero exit status
ERROR: dependency ‘runjags’ is not available for package ‘swfscMisc’
* removing ‘/home/carlson51/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.3/swfscMisc’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘swfscMisc’ had non-zero exit status
```

Comment: Try running `install.packages(c("runjags", "swfscMisc"))`. If you get an error output, add it to your question.

Comment: Updated question above.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Follow the instructions in the [INSTALL file](https://github.com/ku-awdc/runjags/blob/main/INSTALL) of the `runjags` package.

Comment: I got it to work.  I had to remove the pkg-config and then reinstall it.  A few months ago I installed a new version of Linux Ubuntu, so perhaps I needed to update the pkg-config at the same time. Thank you!